# 'svn diff' shows output that seem like no change

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

A certain 'svn diff' on a '.classpath' file gives me the following output. I don't see any difference between the working copy (+) and the pristine copy (-) (do you?). The problem is I haven't changed these files (i.e. I haven't tried to change the build path of the project) but they seem to be modified during build. I use STS 3.3.0.RELEASE, and no 'svn' plugin. I do use maven plugin for eclipse for build.

It would be nice if they were left untouched. Is there a way, I can ensure this? On the other hand, if my '.classpath' file in question is untouched then why is 'svn diff' giving me this output?

Thanks.

```
@@ -1,29 +1,29 @@
-<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<classpath>
-   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
-       <attributes>
-           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
-       </attributes>
-   </classpathentry>
-   <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
-   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
-   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
-       <attributes>
-           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
-       </attributes>
-   </classpathentry>
-   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
-       <attributes>
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
-       </attributes>
-   </classpathentry>
-   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
-       <attributes>
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
-           <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
-       </attributes>
-   </classpathentry>
-   <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
-</classpath>
+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
+<classpath>
+   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
+   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
+   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+           <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
+</classpath>
```

Comment: Maybe all the changes were whitespace?  (tabs vs. spaces, or unix vs. windows line endings...)

Comment: The only diff I can spot is the encoding "UTF-8I" != "UTF-8". Most of the times I had something like this was just as @JimLewis said, whitespaces

Comment: In general, I've found that Eclipse project files don't belong in svn. Since you've tagged the question maven, it's clear that you're using Maven and these files are easily generated. I add these files to svn:ignore and let Maven generate/update them as necessary. You can then avoid running into this issue and needing an answer to this question :)

Comment: @JimLewis I think that could be the case, as I work in a cross-platform environment. I will try and confirm that.

Comment: @Grove The original output doesn't have '|'. The extra '|' got added, I don't know how (while pasting the output on to SO). I've checked my output both of them are 'UTF-8'. I've edited the output to correct that.

Comment: @JoshuaMcKinnon The project uses 'third-party' libraries that aren't  hosted on the maven repository. So I manually add them to the classpath and so I can't 'svn:ignore' on '.classpath' files.

Comment: @RockyInde That itself is a problem that should be fixed. It's not normal to need to do that, even when using third party libraries. I can't fit why into 600 character comment thread adequately, though. It's either an encoding or whitespace issue. If you diff the two files in a visual diff editor that shows visible whitespace, or possibly if you pipe the output of svn diff to a file and view it in a text editor that can do the same, you should see why. It's displaying this because the files are different, but without the exact files on disk we really can't say.

Answer (score 1):

The suspicion raised by @JimLewis and others in the comments below the question was indeed true. Saving the output of the said command into a file and doing a `cat -v` on that file produced the following output:

```
@@ -1,34 +1,34 @@
-<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>^M
-<classpath>^M
-   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>^M
-   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">^M
-       <attributes>^M
-           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>^M
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>^M
-       </attributes>^M
-   </classpathentry>^M
-   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">^M
-       <attributes>^M
-           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>^M
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>^M
-       </attributes>^M
-   </classpathentry>^M
-   <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>^M
-   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.io"/>^M
-   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.config"/>^M
-   <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jars-not-in-maven-repo/eventful.jar"/>^M
-   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.nlp"/>^M
-   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.attrs"/>^M
-   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">^M
-       <attributes>^M
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>^M
-       </attributes>^M
-   </classpathentry>^M
-   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">^M
-       <attributes>^M
-           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>^M
-           <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>^M
-       </attributes>^M
-   </classpathentry>^M
-   <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>^M
-</classpath>^M
+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
+<classpath>
+   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
+   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
+   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.io"/>
+   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.config"/>
+   <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jars-not-in-maven-repo/eventful.jar"/>
+   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.nlp"/>
+   <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/net.holisticlabs.libs.attrs"/>
+   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
+       <attributes>
+           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
+           <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
+       </attributes>
+   </classpathentry>
+   <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
+</classpath>
```

The original '.classpath' was generated on a Windows machine, that uses CRLF newline character while maven on my unix machine replaced them with LF newline characters. As also was suggested, `svn:ignore` or `'svn revert'` could be used to handle such cases.